# Find local or absolute extreme values on open and closed interval.

Tags: calculus

I got the function

$f(x)=x^5+x^3+2x$ on the interval $(a, b]$

And I know that I should find the limit when $x \Rightarrow a+$ and value of $f(b)$. I should also search for undefined values and when $f´(x)=0$ but since I can only work with a and b I have no clue on how to know what is larger then the other. I also don't know how to find the roots of $f´(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$f'(x)=5x^4+3x^2+2=0 \implies 5x^4+3x^2+2=0$$

Use the substitution $u = x^2$ and solve the quadratic equation:

$$5u^2+3u+2=0.$$

After finding the values for $u_{1,2}$ you need to solve $u_{1,2}=x^2$.

For the limits, you can use that the function is continuous on $x\in \mathbb{R}$ hence the limit becomes $f(a)$.